# Unique value hunter easy mode

Tags: python

I want to find the unique values in list2 compared to list1.

```
list1 = ['AAA111', 'BBB111']
list2 = ['BBB111', 'BBB113']
new_list = set(list2) - set(list1)
new_list = ['BBB113']
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, you're asking for an implementation of this theoretical while loop? or are you asking if there is a better/easier/more correct way?

Comment: so you're asking us to write you an implementation? why don't you give it a try and post when you have problems. Stackoverflow is more for technical issues/problems and not really a teaching/implementation site

Comment: I don't understand why you are using these conditionals, you should probably be using "in"

Answer (score 2):

Just use `set`:

```
>>> new_list = set(list2) - set(list1)
>>> new_list
set(['BBB113'])
```

If you need it to be a list, just rebuild a list with the result set:

```
new_list = list(set(list2) - set(list1))
```

Using a (more inefficient) `while loop`:

```
list1 = ['AAA111', 'BBB111']
list2 = ['BBB111', 'BBB113']
new_list = []


while list1 and list2:
  e = list2.pop()
  if e not in list1:
    new_list.append(e)
  else:
    for i in range(len(list1)):
      if list1[i] == e:
        list1.pop(i)
print(new_list)
```

Comment: Why? If you are looking to implement something like this from first principles, you should use another programming language. Otherwise, this is probably the best solution...

Answer (score 0):

If you really really wanted to use a while loop you could do something similar to this, although it feels barbaric.

```
list1 = ['AAA111', 'BBB111']
list2 = ['BBB111', 'BBB113']

i = 0
while i < len(list1):
    if list1[i] in list2:
        list1.pop(i)

    i += 1
```

Comment: doesn't work like that, I think that will just check alphabetical values I think. == will check if they are the same, but > or < don't work that way

Comment: but what does that mean, these are strings, how can they be greater or less than